# Editing text in body of email via Outlook add-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook-addin

The following is an add-in for MS Outlook. One can scan the body of an e-mail and if there is a certain (specific word or pattern) word present, then a MessageBox appears. However, I am wondering if it is possible to change the way a word appears or to edit the text in the body of email, without MessageBox whatsoever. For example, a word (such as the name of the company) can be converted into an hyperlink (i.e. Google to www.google.com or Microsoft to www.microsoft.com) and the user who reads emails on Outlook always sees the hyperlink instead of the word itself.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace FirstOutlookAddIn
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        public static string[] data = new string[10];
        public static Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        Outlook.NameSpace outlookNameSpace;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox;
        Outlook.Items items;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            timer = Stopwatch.StartNew(); ReadMail();
            outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
                    OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            items = inbox.Items;

            items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(ReadSingleMail); // Modified method to run for single email

        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Hinweis: Outlook löst dieses Ereignis nicht mehr aus. Wenn Code vorhanden ist, der 
            // ausgeführt werden muss, wenn Outlook geschlossen wird, informieren Sie sich unter http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506785
        }

        static void ReadSingleMail(dynamic item)
        {
            string bodyText; // Email body
            string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); //Path to My Documents

            if (item != null)
            {
                bodyText = item.Body;
            }
            else
            {
                return; // If no e-mail body, exit function.
            }
        }

        static void ReadMail()
        {
            //Set up OCR
            string bodyText;
            string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

            //Get unread emails from Inbox
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
            app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            Outlook.Items unreadItems = inboxFolder.Items.Restrict("[Unread]=true");
            int max_runs;
            //Go through each Unread email
            if (unreadItems.Count > 10) { max_runs = 10; }
            else max_runs = unreadItems.Count;

            for (int counter = 1; counter <= max_runs; counter++)
            {
                //Reinitialize Data array
                for (int index = 0; index <= 8; index++)
                {
                    data[index] = "";
                }
                dynamic item = unreadItems[counter];
                bodyText = item.Body;
                Match match = Regex.Match(bodyText, "Insert searched pattern here");

                if (match.Success)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(match.Value);
                    match = match.NextMatch();
                }

            }            
        }

        #region Von VSTO generierter Code

        /// <summary>
        /// Erforderliche Methode für die Designerunterstützung.
        /// Der Inhalt der Methode darf nicht mit dem Code-Editor geändert werden.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: what messagebox appears?

Comment: @BugFinder, The messagebox that appears prints the value of the searched word/pattern via regular expression in my example code. It appears because I programmed it in that way just for the sake of example. I hope I was clear and was able to answer your question. If not, please let me know.

Comment: so if you dont want the messagebox, dont code one

Comment: @BugFinder, yes. But my question was about whether it is possible to edit the text in the email body of incoming emails. MessageBox was just an example for demonstrative purposes. I wanted to show what I tried so far.

Comment: Well.. can and should would be different things, but of course you can receive an email, have it auto change stuff in the mail and save it.. you can do it with a rule in outlook ..  but you need to go try that

Comment: @BugFinder, unfortunately it is not possible to create a rule for this particular purpose. One can create a rule for a specific word and then choose what happens but editing the found word is not one of the options.

Comment: i said you CAN do it with a rule - I didnt say how or that you should.. and no its not a default option.. but for example I have a rule that saves a mail I get every day and saves the attachment to a specific place.  you CAN do it, I didnt tell you how as thats not this question..  It sounds like you arent trying tbh and as the only one answering, im gonna dip out here. But lookup how to monitor for mails arriving, and edit it..

Comment: @BugFinder, no it is not possible to do it with a rule. I was trying a lot to find a solution my problem. But I haven't been able to. That is why I asked it here.

Comment: Your choice but Im done. You havent even used the info youve been given.

Comment: @BugFinder, you haven't provided the information that I needed. If you did, I am still unable to see it despite many tries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the function ReadMail() as below replaces text, as I want it.

```
static void ReadMail(){
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
    app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    Outlook.Items Items = inboxFolder.Items.Restrict("[LastModificationTime] > '01/1/2003'");

    foreach (var item in Items){
        var mail = (Outlook.MailItem)item;
        mail.Body = mail.Body.Replace("Text to be replaced", "Replacing text");
        mail.Save();
    }

}
```